# At what point should I bring things to a mods attention?

Tags: discussion

There's a user that I feel isn't upholding the Etiquette described in the FAQs.

To the point that they are editing my questions in an attempt to belittle the question.

At what point should I start getting moderator attention?

Answer (score 2):

If you see someone doing something that's out of place, flag it for moderator attention and we'll look at it. It's better to err on the side of caution than to wait and let a problem get out of hand.

Comment: Ok. Well there's someone who keeps editing my question adding information that has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Flag the post where the user is doing this for moderator attention and we'll look at it.